# "Have a good day" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, saludos

I really like the usage of the sentence "Have a good day" in English. It gives a good vibration when saying goodbye to someone.

In Spanish is not very common to use it, so every time I want to use it I keep wondering: which of these should be the preferred way?

> Ten un buen día
>
> Que tengas un buen día

or even

> Que vaya bien

In case it needs to be specific, I would rather chose a Spanish from Spain version.

Comment: Both "que tengas un buen día" and "que te vaya bien" sound fine.

Comment: When in the morning I meet  my neighbors in the elevator, obviously I say "buenos días" but my usual good bye is **"feliz día"**. I omit (que tengas) since it should be a short bye when each of us get off on different floors. I prefer 'feliz' to 'buen' since I think 'feliz' not only implies good but even more.

Comment: Interestingly the phrase 'Have a nice day' is very common. I think it may have been an import from the US. To my ears Have a good day sounds as though they really mean it more than Have a nice day which they learned at charm school. Not sure whether any of the proposed translations have that distinction.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The short answer would be

> Que tengas un buen día

Which express your desire for the other person to actually `"have a nice day"`.

`"Ten un buen día"` is the literal translation but it doesn't express the sentiment behind `"have a nice day"`. It could be used to maybe cheer someone up; something like `"Hey you, go and have a nice day"` or something like that.

`"Que vaya bien"` is not entirely correct. It would be more like `"Que te vaya bien"` and it is most commonly used when someone is going to do something, maybe when someone is going to a job interview, you can tell him `"Que te vaya bien"` to express your desire for the interview to go well.

But for saying goodbye the most common way is `"Que tengas un buen día"`, `"Que tengas buen día"` or as mentioned in the comments `"Feliz día`".

Also remember that, in some cultures and countries, when you want to speak with more respect (to older people, for example) you would say `"Que tenga un buen día"` since `"tengas"` is a more personal manner.

Comment: Welcome to the SE. It's a very good first answer. +1

Comment: In fact, even in Spain, where *tú* is widely used, I think the *usted* version of this sentence is more usual, since it is a bit too polite. If I take a taxi here in Madrid in the morning, it is quite usual that the last words I hear from the driver are *adiós y que tenga un buen día*.

Comment: Just to add another option: `Que pase/s un buen día` could be also a valid one.

Answer (score 5):

> Que tenga buen día.

or the more familiar, but less commonly heard:

> Que tengas buen día.

Are both very common in Mexico and Guatemala (the countries with which I am most familiar).  Even more common, especially as a closing of a business transaction (a store clerk would say it to you as you're finishing paying):

> Que te vaya bien.

Comment: Interesting, so in Mexico and Guatemala they drop the _un_ from _Que tenga un buen día_.

Comment: Yes.   I asked my wife (a Guatamalan native) about it, and she said that both are acceptable, but without the 'un' is far more common. Which matches my experience, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your second proposal might be expressed in this formal way:

> ¡Que le vaya bien! (a usted)